# Chrome refreshing page infinitely with Webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

I am working on a React based app which uses Webpack as dev server. I am experiencing some really wierd behaviour. Whenever I make any changes, the app recompiles and Chrome reloads the page in localhost. However, after this it keep reloading the page infinitely, even though I don't see webpack doing any re-compilations. Looking for some insights into this.

This is my webpack.config:

```
{
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      react: require.resolve('react'),
      'react-dom': require.resolve('react-dom'),
      'react-router-dom': require.resolve('react-router-dom'),
      'spectra-ui-commons$': require.resolve('spectra-ui-commons')
    }
  },
  entry: {
    'app-shell': APP_PATH
  },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: isDev ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        include: `${APP_PATH}/apps`,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'svg-sprite-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: BUILD_PATH,
      staticOptions: {},
      watch: true,
      publicPath: '/build/app/'
    },
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true
    },
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://[::1]:8081'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: isDev ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.env': JSON.stringify(process.env.env || 'development'),
      'env.backendHost': JSON.stringify('http://localhost:8081')
    })
  ]
};
```

EDIT: I am still having the same issue but I am now getting the following error on my Node server:
`Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000 to http://[::1]:8081/ [ECONNRESET]`

Comment: why not use create-react-app and then eject? perfect webpack config

Comment: The app is few years old and wasn't created with create-react-app.

Comment: odd, I thought from this line: `I am creating React based app which uses Webpack as dev server` it was a new app

Comment: Corrected the description.